# jquery code is not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Good day All,

I've faced a problem using a jquery script on my html page.

The script works fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4xSf/)

On my page I used:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>  <script src="bookform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Pickup location:<br><input placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="date" name="date" required="required">
 Name on meeting plate:<br><input type="text" name="name" required><br>
 Your phone number:<br><input type="text" name="phone" required><br>
Time of pickup:<br> <input class="large" type="text" name="time" required="required"><br>
Pickup location:<br> 
          <select name="select1" id="select1">
            <option>Where to pickup</option>
            <option value="pick_airport">Airport</option>
            <option value="pick_railway">Railway station</option>
            <option value="pick_address">Address</option>
          </select>
    <div id ="pick_nextStep"></div>
    Dropoff location:<br>
          <select name="select2" id="select2">
              <option>Where to dropoff</option>
            <option value="drop_airport">Airport</option>
            <option value="drop_railway">Railway station</option>
            <option value="drop_address">Address</option>
          </select>
    <div id ="drop_nextStep"></div>
```

But on page load it does notwork.

Comment: have you added the script in page head??

Comment: yes I used <script src=>

Comment: No. You need to include inside <head></head>

Comment: not in script tag, in head section we are talking about here.

Comment: yeap. exapmle at http://new.taximario.com/bookform.html

Comment: I think the jquery path form bookform.js be incorrect.

Comment: A HTML page should have `<html>` and `</html>` tags, as well as `<body>` and `</body>` tags. It should look something like this: `<html><head>// load scripts</head><body>//your content</body></html>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wrap the code of `bookform.js` inside DOM ready handler, just like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#select1').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'pick_airport'){
        $('#pick_nextStep').html('<select name="pickup_location" required="required" id="select1"><option>Select airport</option><option value="Sheremetievo (SVO)">Sheremetievo (SVO)</option><option value="Domodedovo (DME)">Domodedovo (DME)</option><option value="Vnukovo (VKO)">Vnukovo (VKO)</option></select><br>Flight: <br><input  type="text" name="flight" required size="20" maxlength="255">');
    }
    if($(this).val() == 'pick_railway'){
       $('#pick_nextStep').html('<select name="pickup_location" required="required" id="select1"><option value="Belorusskiy">Belorusskiy</option><option value="Kazanskiy">Kazanskiy</option><option value="Kurskiy">Kurskiy</option><option value="Kievskiy">Kievskiy</option><option value="Leningradskiy">Leningradskiy</option><option value="Paveleckiy">Paveleckiy</option><option value="Rizskiy">Rizskiy</option><option value="Saveloskiy">Savelovskiy</option><option value="Yaroslavskiy">Yaroslavskiy</option></select><br>Wagon:<br><input  type="text" name="flight" required size="20" maxlength="255">'); 
    }
    if($(this).val() == 'pick_address'){
        $('#pick_nextStep').html('Pickup address:<br><input name="pickup_location" type="text" size="20" maxlength="255">');
    }
});
$('#select2').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'drop_airport'){
        $('#drop_nextStep').html('<select name="pickup_location" required="required" id="select1"><option>Select airport</option><option value="Sheremetievo (SVO)">Sheremetievo (SVO)</option><option value="Domodedovo (DME)">Domodedovo (DME)</option><option value="Vnukovo (VKO)">Vnukovo (VKO)</option></select><br>');
    }
     if($(this).val() == 'drop_railway'){
       $('#drop_nextStep').html('<select name="pickup_location" required="required" id="select2"><option value="Belorusskiy">Belorusskiy</option><option value="Kazanskiy">Kazanskiy</option><option value="Kurskiy">Kurskiy</option><option value="Kievskiy">Kievskiy</option><option value="Leningradskiy">Leningradskiy</option><option value="Paveleckiy">Paveleckiy</option><option value="Rizskiy">Rizskiy</option><option value="Saveloskiy">Savelovskiy</option><option value="Yaroslavskiy">Yaroslavskiy</option></select>')
     }
    if($(this).val() == 'drop_address'){
        $('#drop_nextStep').html('Your destination address:<br><input type="text" name="dropoff_location" required>');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked fine. Can you point me to where i can read more about DOM ready?

Comment: You can read about it on the jQuery Api documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You could also place all JS files on the bottom of the page (before closing </body>), the result be the same as DOMContentReady.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {....})` or shorter form `$(function() {....})` to make sure all your DOM elements are loaded properly before executing your jQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Did it. The same situation

Comment: Your page doesn't have any `<html>` or `<body>` tag at all?

Answer (score 1):

Add the script tag for jquery library in head tag of page.Like this:

```
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is that your script loads AFTER the all DOM elements are being loaded.

You need to inverse that. There are two answers above: one says to include your `<script></script>` tag inside the `<head>` container.

It may work, but the script may shot before the whole page is loaded. To prevent this from happening, simply wrap all your jQuery code into this function:

```
$(function(), { 
  // your code here;
});
```

It is the same as `$(document).ready()` and so on.

If still does not work, try to enable a console (by pressing F12 in Google Chrome and search for errors).