# Dynamically append jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically include the div-structure from a jQuery slider into my index page.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".abc", function() {
    var photo = '<li><img src="img/photos/photo-1.png" title="Photo 1"></li>';
    // .. other li's
    $('#banner-fade ul.bjqs').append(photo);
});
```

into:

```
<div class="slider" id="photo_1">
    <div id="banner-fade">
    <ul class="bjqs">
            // here should the list items come.
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the javascript is not working, only the first picture is shown. How is this possible?

-> When I paste the li's inside the ul, it will work. But not when I try to append it using jQuery.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/LytSC/

Comment: here where you have define "abc" class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/psTC9/

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on( "click", ".abc", function() {
    var photo = '<li><b>test1</b></li>';
    $('#banner-fade ul.bjqs').append(photo);
  });
});
```

check this - http://jsfiddle.net/6a6Fx/2/

Comment: That worked but the problem is the javascript is not working when I dynamically include the div-structure (The li's in this case). When I paste the li's in the index file it will work, but not when I append it using jQuery.

Comment: @user3231419 can you provide fiddler please

Answer (score 0):

Look like the same thing I've just answered in other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194655/jquery-code-is-not-working/22194917#22194917).

All you need to do is to wrap your code inside

```
$(function(), {
  // Your code goes here...
});
```

And make sure your `<script></script>` tags are both inside `<head>` container.